# Can you force show three-dot drop down option menu in Android ICS?

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, popupmenu

I am trying to find a way to force show the three-dot drop down menu in Android ICS. I know it supposed to show when there is a lack of a hard button for settings/menu.

Here is a screenshot of what I'm referring to:

http://cdn.gottabemobile.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/12/ICS-Screen05.jpg

Thanks!

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: We were just going to put a popdown menu in the same style but it'd be redundant if the overflow menu came up due to a lack of a hardware menu key.

Answer (score 1):

You can force items to appear in the overflow menu by using `android:showAsAction="never"` in your menu XML. However, if your device has a hardware menu key, then the overflow won't display. You would have to do some fakery with a an item that you clicked, and dropped down a custom Context Menu or something.

I ran into this with my app too, and as much as I'd prefer to force it, it's probably best to go with the expected platform behavior and leave it to the menu button.

Comment: I agree with you, we decided to just stick with convention.

Comment: There appears to be far too much inconsistency with the action bar. In my opinion the options menu was far more consistent.

Answer (score 1):

So, turns out it's pretty simple, I recently implemented in my app.

The items that need to be shown in the overflow menu, nest them under one menu item as follows:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/empty"
        android:orderInCategory="101"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_overflow">

        <menu>        

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_settings"
                android:orderInCategory="96"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/menu_settings"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_settings"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_share"
                android:orderInCategory="97"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/menu_share"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_share"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_rate"
                android:orderInCategory="98"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/menu_rate"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_important"/>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/action_feedback"
                android:orderInCategory="99"
                android:showAsAction="never"
                android:title="@string/menu_feedback"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_edit"/>

            </menu>         
        </item>
</menu>
```

Now, edit the main activity file as follows:

```
package com.example.test;
//all your import statements go here

Menu mainMenu=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); }

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {     
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
mainMenu=menu;
return true; }


//Menu press should open 3 dot menu
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU) {
        mainMenu.performIdentifierAction(R.id.empty, 0);
        return true; }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event); }
```